# Flask-SQLAlchemy number of results in query

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I was wondering if anyone knows how to output the number of results from a query in a flask template.

Example view code:

```
products = Product.query.all()
```

In the template it would be handy to be able to just do:

```
{{ products.count() }}
```

Is there anyway to do this already, or does anyone have a filter written that does this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your `products` template variable is a regular list. You can use the `length` filter to gets its size:

```
{{ products|length }}
```

But if you are working with paginated results then this will give you the size of one page. If you want the size of the entire query then you have to call `count()` on the query object. For example:

```
product_count = Product.query.count()
```

Then pass this to the template as an additional argument. Or if you prefer you can pass the query object to the template and call `count()` from there:

```
{{ product_query.count() }}
```

Comment: cheers, I wrote a filter that handles it in case a query is a None type as well.

Comment: Count triggers a SQL query, yes.

Comment: But this solution is quite slow when table is huge, is there any other way to get the count？

Comment: Getting the count is in general very efficient. Not sure what database you are using, all major databases can do this actually from the table indices, and without having to count items one by one.

Answer (score -3):

you can use `len(products)` , 
it is standart python function and works for me

Comment: It only works if you call the .all() method as it returns the results of the query as a list.